# How do I get the last segment of URL using regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, url-rewriting

I have a URL:

```
www.domain.com/first/second/last/
```

How do I get the last term between slashes? i.e. `last` using regular expressions?

Please note that the URL could just be:

```
www.domain.com/last/
```

Or:

```
www.domain.com/first/second/third/fourth/last/
```

I need to extract this last term for use in the Zeus Server's Request Rewrite module which uses PERL and REGEX.

#### Update

After implementing some answers, I have just realized that I need this match to be made only on URLs in a certain directory.

i.e.

```
www.domain.com/directory/first/second/last/
```

should return `last`. Whereas:

```
www.domain.com/first/second/last/
```

should not return a match.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's a simple regex:

```
[^/]+(?=/$|$)
```

Should match anything you throw at it.

---

If you want to look in a particular directory, use this:

```
/directory.*/([^/]+)/?$
```

and your result will be in the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks! This works. But I've just realised that I need to extract the last segment for URLS that are only in a particular directory. ie www.domain.com/directory/first/second/last/

Can you make a further suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: @Matt - I see now (in RegexBuddy) that [PERL does not support variable repetition inside lookbehind](http://regexr.com?2vlvc). You'll have to check separately if it's inside that particular directory - unless you want to use a capture group.

Comment: /directory/.*([^/]+)/?$ is only returning the last character ie't'instead of 'last

Comment: This does not work with a query string (it captures the query string) https://regex101.com/r/Oo3Wk7/1

Answer (score 12):

This regex (a slightly modified version of Joseph's answer), should give you the last segment, minus ending slash.

```
([^/]+)/?$
```

Your result will be the first capture group.

Comment: For people looking for a RE2-compatible solution (Go, Google Sheets) this one worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
[^/]+(?=/$|$)
```

With a `(?=lookahead)` you won't get the last slash.

`[^/]+`  Looks for at least one character that is not a slash (as many as possible).
`(?=/?^|^)` makes sure that the next part of the string is a / and then the end of string or just end of string.

Matches `match` in `/one/two/match`, '/one/two/match/'.

Answer (score 0):

The last slash might be optional. Right?

How about something like this:

```
$url =~ m|([^/]+)/?$|;
my $end_of_url = $1;
```

The `$` on the end anchors the regular expression to the end of the string. The `[^/]` means anything that's not a slash and the `+` after means I want one or more things that are not slashes. Notice that this is in a capture group which are marked with parentheses.

I end the regular expression with `/?` which means that there may or may not be a slash on the very end of the string. I've put my regular expression between `m|` and `|`, so I can use forward slashes without having to constantly escape them.

The last part of the URL is now in `$1` and I can set my own scalar variable to save this result.