# How to regex last part of URL only?

Tags: regex, string, url, regular-language

I want to do a regex that target the end of a url:

`www.company.com/orders/`**thanks**

If you return from email or account page order ID is populated in the end:

www.company.com/orders/thanks/**1sfasd523425**

So I only want to target the URL that ends with **/thanks**

This thread bring is similiar: [How do I get the last segment of URL using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798187/how-do-i-get-the-last-segment-of-url-using-regular-expressions)

Had something similair `.*\/thanks\/.+` but target incorrectly.

**EDIT: Only target URLs ending with /thanks or /thanks/**

Comment: *I only want to target the URL that ends with /thanks*  - That thread you linked to is what you need. `/thanks/?$`

Comment: `\/thanks\/[^\/]+$` will work

Comment: I don't quite follow you... Are you after to **match** only URL's ending in */thanks*? Then match against `\/thanks$`. If you want to get the last part - then what @rock321987 said.

Comment: @ClasG I am also confused

Comment: then @WiktorStribiżew solution will work

Comment: I only want to target URLs ending with /thanks \/thanks$ doesn't return anything using http://regexr.com/

Comment: .+(?=\/thanks$).+ works!

Comment: this will also suffice :- https://regex101.com/r/lS7lH9/2

Comment: @rock321987 why does it end with /gm ?

Comment: @rock321987: That won't match whole URL.

Comment: @noob sorry, I thought it was only about checking

Comment: @Hbaecklund: Use `/thanks/?$` - you were testing it at the online tester with *several* lines, you need to use `/m` multiline modifier to make `$` match the end of the line (usually, `$` matches the end of the string).

Comment: `g` is the global flag..`m` is the multiline flag..hover over the `?` on `regex101`, it is explained there

Comment: @rock321987 because if I do not have /gm there's no match, do I need to add /gm to the regex ?

Comment: tell the language you are using?

Comment: @rock321987 just url ?

Comment: these flags are language specific and not provided by `regular expressions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with lookahead like this.

**Regex:** `.+(?=\/thanks$).+`

**Explanation:** This will match the URL only if `thanks` is at end of string by `positive lookahead`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lS7lH9/1)**

Comment: What an ugly pattern (`.+(?=\/thanks$).+`). Anchor the lookahead at the start at least.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Looks symmetric and beautiful to me. And it works in this case too.

Comment: takes `2011` steps..don't you think that's an overkill

Comment: @rock321987: That's because there are two URL. If you take one URL at a time then it's less than 30 steps.

Comment: @noob: Best testing of a regex is performed on a string that does not match the pattern. And what works best is `/thanks/?$` (if it is for apache, no escaping `/` is necessary and the last `/?` is a good idea since a URL can end with a `/`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: And now we are going into _what might not match._ I will leave that  upto OP to add more inputs. I can see many possible cases where my regex won't be useful but I guess is that the case with OP ?

Comment: @Hbaecklund: In that case only slight change in my regex `.+(?=\/thanks\/?$).+` would be okay. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lS7lH9/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
Use URL object dont parse it yourself 

URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616915/how-to-regex-last-part-of-url-only");
URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), "utf-8");
url.getPath();
url.getContent();
url.getPort();
url.getContent();
```