# URL last part regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get the last part of my URL with html on the end. So if I have this url `http://step/build/index.html` I need to get only `index.html`. I need to do this with javascript

```
let address = http://step/build/index.html;
let result = address.match(/html/i);
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work for me, maybe I make some mistakes. 
[How do I get the last segment of URL using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798187/how-do-i-get-the-last-segment-of-url-using-regular-expressions)
Could someone help me and explain it in details?
Thank you.

Comment: Will your URL always end with `.html`?

Answer (score 3):

You could split it on slashes and then fetch the last item:

```js
let address = "http://step/build/index.html";
let result = address.split("/").pop();
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the `.html` filename part using this `/[^/]+\.html/i` RegEx.

See the code below.

```js
const regex = /[^/]+\.html/i;

let address = "http://step/build/index.html";
let result = address.match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

The same RegEx will also match the filename incase the URL has additional parameters.

```js
const regex = /[^/]+\.html/i;

let address = "http://step/build/index.html?name=value";
let result = address.match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I would highlight the second use case. It makes it stand out as a more viable answer!

Comment: It's better to expand match scope of second regex: `/([^/?&#]+)(?![^/]*/)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which returns an array to split on a forward slash and then use [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) which removes the last element from the array and returns that:

```js
let address = "http://step/build/index.html".split('/').pop();
console.log(address);
```

If you have querystring parameters which could for example start with `?` or `#`, you might use split again and get the first item from the array:

```js
let address2 = "\"http://step/build/index.html?id=1&cat=2"
  .split('/')
  .pop()
  .split(/[?#]/)[0];
console.log(address2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-regex approach. Should be more reliable/appropriate at the job, depending on whether you'll need other URL-specific parts:

```js
// Note the ?foo=bar part, that URL.pathname will ignore below
let address = 'http://step/build/index.html?foo=bar';

let url = new URL(address);

// Last part of the path
console.log(url.pathname.split('/').pop());
// Query string
console.log(url.search);
// Whole data
console.log(url);
```